# Javafx change text before and after run task

Tags: multithreading, label, task, javafx-2

I would like to update some text of my status bar label before and after I run a task.
This is the example code:

```
    label.setText("please wait...");

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            veryLongOperation();
            return null;
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();

    while (thread.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("waiting...");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
    }

    System.out.println("work done!");
    label.setText("work done!");
```

With this example the text value of label can't be changed... how can I update the text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override [the `Task#suceeded` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#succeeded%28%29) like this:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        veryLongOperation();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        System.out.println("work done!");
        label.setText("work done!");
    }
};

new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: I am sorry i not specify that my gui is freezed when i run a task. How change the value of a text label, and not freeze all the mask?

Comment: @Cizu The reason is the `while (thread.isAlive()) {System.out.println("waiting..."); Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);}` part: it sleeps on the UI thread which then becomes unresponsive. With my proposed approach, you don't need to sleep any more.

Comment: Another solution - is to call Platform.runLater(...) method, which will call label.setText("work done!"), inside the succeeded method. Because code, which is present, is not correct from a point of view, that all manipulations with javafx objects should be done on JFX thread. As I see, succeeded() method is called not on a JFX thread. Anyway, Platform.runLater() is a good solution for interaction with JFX UI.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov *The protected convenience method succeeded is invoked on the JavaFX Application thread.* ([at the bottom of this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm))